# How to use Resilience4j Time limiter for synchronous Request

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, resilience4j

I used Resilience4j API to implement timelimiter functionality for my application

But it will accept return type only **CompletableFuture, Mono, FLux** (non blocking queue)

So how to use for **ResponseEntity OR any Return type** can accept, which mean i want to use time limiter for blocking queue request.

Help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only use TimeLimiter with asynchronous calls. Some more information here: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/430